# Formatting credit card input like (xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx) in android

Tags: android

How to set credit card number in above format(spaces in between) in android? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What you want actually?

Comment: i have to check  whether the user enters valid credit card number or not. ie (9999 9999 9999 9999) have to give in this format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you want to do like, as user provides input in edittext after every four characters typed, a space should be placed after it.

If this is the thing you need, then you can implement:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           // apply your logic for putting space after every four characters typed
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

**Edit:**

I think you can use `PatternMatcher` class. Follow these links on [developer.android.com]:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PatternMatcher.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Check the tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
private String _ccNumber = "";

cc_no.addTextChangedListener(ccWatcher);

private TextWatcher ccWatcher= new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(_ccNumber.length() < s.length()){

            switch(s.length()){
                case 6:
                    s.insert(5, " ");
                    break;
                case 11:
                    s.insert(10, " ");
                    break;
                case 16:
                    s.insert(15, " ");
                    break;
            }
        }
        _ccNumber = s.toString();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  //get the reference of this edit text field
 EditText  etNICNO_Sender=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNICNO_Sender);
    /*add textChangeListner with TextWatcher argument
        by adding text change listner with text watcher we can get three methods of
        Edit Text 1) onTextChanged 2) beforeTextChanged 3) afterTextChanged
        these methods work when user types in text feild.
     */
 etNICNO_Sender.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   int len=0;
   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  String str = etNICNO_Sender.getText().toString();

  if((str.length()==5 && len <str.length()) || (str.length()==10 && len <str.length()) || (str.length()==15 && len <str.length())){
                  //checking length  for backspace.
                  etNICNO_Sender.append(" "); //append space
                 }
   }
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
     int after) {
    String str = etNICNO_Sender.getText().toString();
                         len = str.length();
        }
   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
  });
```

this worked for me,like charm! see [here](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-apply-niccustom-format-to-edit.html) for complete code snippet just you need to append space automatically,i use to append hyphen automatically

Comment: if the user enters the card number it should automatically leave spaces in between. How to implement this?