# Android - How to get edittext as in this xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-x format?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to show the number in this **xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-x** format on EditText.

Eg (01-140-176-515-4)

I tried modifying the below code which displays the number in credit card number format 
**(xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx)**

```
et_cardnumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private static final int TOTAL_SYMBOLS = 19; // size of pattern 0000-0000-0000-0000
        private static final int TOTAL_DIGITS = 16; // max numbers of digits in pattern: 0000 x 4
        private static final int DIVIDER_MODULO = 5; // means divider position is every 5th symbol beginning with 1
        private static final int DIVIDER_POSITION = DIVIDER_MODULO - 1; // means divider position is every 4th symbol beginning with 0
        private static final char DIVIDER = '-';

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // noop
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            iv_cardtype.setImageResource(getCreditCardTypeForImageView(et_cardnumber.getText().toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!isInputCorrect(s, TOTAL_SYMBOLS, DIVIDER_MODULO, DIVIDER)) {
                s.replace(0, s.length(), buildCorrecntString(getDigitArray(s, TOTAL_DIGITS), DIVIDER_POSITION, DIVIDER));
            }
        }

        private boolean isInputCorrect(Editable s, int totalSymbols, int dividerModulo, char divider) {
            boolean isCorrect = s.length() <= totalSymbols; // check size of entered string
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { // chech that every element is right
                if (i > 0 && (i + 1) % dividerModulo == 0) {
                    isCorrect &= divider == s.charAt(i);
                } else {
                    isCorrect &= Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            return isCorrect;
        }

        private String buildCorrecntString(char[] digits, int dividerPosition, char divider) {
            final StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
                if (digits[i] != 0) {
                    formatted.append(digits[i]);
                    if ((i > 0) && (i < (digits.length - 1)) && (((i + 1) % dividerPosition) == 0)) {
                        formatted.append(divider);
                    }
                }
            }

            return formatted.toString();
        }

        private char[] getDigitArray(final Editable s, final int size) {
            char[] digits = new char[size];
            int index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length() && index < size; i++) {
                char current = s.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isDigit(current)) {
                    digits[index] = current;
                    index++;
                }
            }
            return digits;
        }
    });
```

I couldn't get it right when i make changes to get the format which i want.

Can anyone help me to get the number in **xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-x** format?

Comment: Has been discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801285/formatting-credit-card-input-like-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-in-android) already.

Comment: @AneebKhawar yes, that is creditcard number format. If i just append a '-' character to which the format(xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-x) i want, it is not getting deleted on backspace key press.

Comment: have seen this ?? https://github.com/pinball83/Masked-Edittext

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much in Android , but try to build something like this .

```js
str Yourstring = "";
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
                if (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8 || i == 11) {
                    Yourstring = Yourstring + "-" +digits[i];
                  }
              else 
                  {
                    Yourstring = Yourstring +digits[i];
                  }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered this already in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39012423/6295668) , please change the logic according to your format

Comment: Thanks, It works. But failed to display the format in below scenarios.

1. If we paste the copied number on edit text, it fails to display the number in format (xx-xxx-xxx-xxx-x),
2. And if we enter a number in middle of the EditText, it again fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library.
it will  allow  according yo your formate

[EditText Pattern lib](https://github.com/faradaj/PatternedEditText)